# Não consigo realizar a soma dos 100 primeiros números primos, onde estou errando?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```py
#python3.7

cont = 0
cont_100 = 0
primos = 0
num = 1
soma = 0
while True:
    primos += 1

    while primos != num:
        if primos % num == 0:
            num += 1
            cont += 1
    if cont == 2:
        soma += primos
    num = 1

    cont_100 += 1
    if cont_100 == 100:
        break
print(soma)
```

Comment: Consegue fazer o teste de mesa do seu código e postar junto na pergunta?

Answer (score 3):

Tem alguns erros no seu código:

- O `cont` tem que ser zerado a cada iteração;
- A condição do segundo `while` deveria ser `primos >= num`;
- A variável `num` deve ser incrementada a cada iteração do laço interno, não somente quando `primos % num == 0`;
- E você só pode incrementar `cont_100` quando o número é primo, ou seja, no `if cont == 2`.

Segue a versão do seu código corrigida:

```py
#python3.7

cont_100 = 0
primos = 0
num = 1
soma = 0
while True:
    primos += 1
    cont = 0

    while primos >= num:
        if primos % num == 0:
            cont += 1
        num += 1

    if cont == 2:
        soma += primos
        cont_100 += 1
    num = 1

    if cont_100 == 100:
        break
print(soma)
```

E uma versão com algumas mudanças que eu fiz:

```py
#python3.7

cont_100 = 0
primos = 0
soma = 0

while cont_100 < 100:
    primos += 1
    num = 1
    cont = 0

    while primos >= num/2:
        if primos % num == 0:
            cont += 1
        num += 1

    if cont == 2:
        soma += primos
        cont_100 += 1

print(soma)
```

Comment: Perfeito! Eu ainda consegui resolvendo com while pra repetir as 100x e um for in range pra testar se o numero é primo. Mas essa sua forma apenas com while ficou bem melhor. Obrigado!!

Answer (score 0):

Segue a minha solução, favor testar.

Basicamente eu testo se um numero é primo e caso seja ele adicionado na lista `primos`.

Quando a lista `primos` tiver 100 elementos o 'loop' termina e exibe a soma de todos os elementos da lista `primos`.

```
primos = []
numero = 0

while len(primos) != 100:        

    total = 0

    for n in range(1, numero + 1):        
        if numero % n == 0:
            total += 1        

    if total == 2:
        # É primo porque o resto da divisão foi igual a zero duas vezes
        # Em outras palavras, o número foi divisivel por 1 e por ele mesmo
        primos.append(numero)

    numero += 1

print(sum(primos))
```

Comment: Você pode deixar mais rápido fazendo o cálculo até número / 2. Porque não tem como um número ser divisível por um número maior que sua metade.

Comment: Kevin, grato pela contribuição! Como ficaria? Não consegui aqui...

Comment: Na verdade vc só precisa ir até a raiz quadrada do número, e pulando de 2 em 2 (não tem porque dividir por números pares, vc pode testar se é par antes de fazer o `for`, assim já evita o loop caso o número seja par - exceto se for 2, que é o único primo que tb é par, e até compensa fazer um `if` específico antes do `for`). Se quiser mesmo usar algoritmos mais eficientes, há vários listados [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53451147)

Comment: Entendi, vou ver os algoritmos que você sugeriu. Grato hkotsubo!

Comment: Muito obrigado! Ficou bem parecido com o que eu consegui resolver. A diferença é que eu não usei (por não saber) a lista... Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver esta questão implementei o seguinte código:

```
# Este programa calcula a soma dos "n" primeiros números primos.


def soma_primos(n):
    li = 2
    primos = list()
    while len(primos) < n:
        if primo(li):
            primos.append(li)
        li += 1
    return sum(primos)


def primo(m):
    i = 1
    cont = 0
    while i <= m:
        if m % i == 0:
            cont += 1
        i += 1
    if cont != 2:
        return False
    else:
        return True


num = int(input('Desejas calcular a soma de quantos primeiros números primos? '))

print(f'A soma do {num} primeiros números primos são:\n{soma_primos(num)}')
```

Observe que quando executamos o código recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Desejas calcular a soma de quantos primeiros números primos?` . Neste momento devemos digitar a quantidade dos primeiros números primos. Posteriormente a quantidade é passada como parâmetro para a função `soma_primos()`. Chegando lá, o bloco `while` executará várias iterações até que o tamanho de `primos` seja o **antecessor** de `n`. Para cada execução da iteração o bloco `if` verificará se o valor de `li` é primo. **Neste momento a será perguntada a função `primo()` se o valor `li` é primo**. Caso a resposta da função `primo()` seja **True**, o valor correspondente é adicionado à lista `primos`. Estas operações de verificações são realizadas até que a lista `primos` esteja completa. Depois que a lista `primos` estiver completa será calculada a soma de seus valores e, em seguida, exibido o resultado ao usuário.

**Testando o código**

**Exemplo 1**

digitando o valor...

```
3
```

Obteremos como soma o resultado

```
10
```

...e de fato a soma dos **3** primeiros primos é:

```
2 + 3 + 5 = 10
```

**Exemplo 2**

Se digitarmos

```
100
```

Obteremos como resultado o valor:

```
24133
```

Pois a soma dos **100** primeiros números primos é **24133**.

**OBSERVAÇÃO**

Este código é suficiente para calcular a **soma** de quaisquer **n** primeiros números **primos**.